# How can I revert version info keys to use the base target configuration?

Tags: configuration, target, revert, c++builder-xe7, versioninfo

In C++ Builder XE7 (I guess it is the same in all versions), in `Project Options` under `Version Info`. if I for example select the target `Debug build configuration` and sets a value for the `File description` key. Then later on I do the same in the target `All configurations`. Now I want the key in `Debug build configuration` to use the value set in `All configurations`.

It seems like as soon I have change anything in the `Version Info` I can't revert it back to use the settings under `All configurations` (Base configuration).
On almost all the other groups I can expand each option and remove the value to get the base value. But this isn't possible in `Version Info`

The only solution I have now is to hack the project file, but I guess there must be an easier way to revert these data.

Comment: Hacking the project file to remove the offending version info from the "debug" configuration group (actually, from all groups other than the base group) is the only way. This is a known issue that has never been fixed in the IDE (even though it has existed for YEARS, and there are bug reports about it). There are 3rd party solutions to work around it, though.

Comment: Okay, Remy. Thank you for the info.